# Why doesn't opencv give this rectangle a colour using python's cv2

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

The following code draws a white rectangle. However it is not supposed to do that.
Considering opencv uses BGR colorspace, it should look like this http://www.colorpicker.com/?colorcode=9F635F

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = np.zeros([500, 500, 3])
cv2.rectangle(drawing, (0, 0), (250, 250), (95, 99, 159), -1)
cv2.imshow("drawing", drawing)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will draw fine if you change

```
drawing = np.zeros([500, 500, 3])
```

to

```
drawing = np.zeros([500, 500, 3], np.uint8)
```

Otherwise, the image will be of 32F type.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, but does it have something to do with the "drawing" argument defaulting to grayscale?