# white border while displaying a full image with python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

This question is related with this one:
[how to display a full screen images with python2.7 and opencv2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696061/how-to-display-a-full-screen-images-with-python2-7-and-opencv2-4)

I want to display a black image full screen, i have created even a black image with the same resolution of the screen.
But i get a little white stripe on top and on the left of the screen.
I don't know if it is a problem of my screen that is not aligned or its my code. I have tried in 2 displays and the white stripe is displayed.

So if you run this code below, do you get a full black image?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2



    if __name__ == "__main__":
        img =  cv2.imread('nero.jpg')
        cv2.namedWindow("test", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.setWindowProperty("test", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.imshow("test",img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

EDIT :
This method is not working for me. do you know anther way or libraries to display a full screen image?

EDIT 2: still unsolved, i am starting to think that it is an openCv bug

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, there is a white stripe of 1 pixel on the left and on the top side of the window. Tested it with multiple monitors. OpenCV version 3.4.2

But there is a workaround which works perfectly fine in my case (see also https://gist.github.com/goraj/a2916da98806e30423d27671cfee21b6). Here's the code:

```py
import cv2
import win32api
import win32gui

cv2.namedWindow("fullScreen", cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
cv2.setWindowProperty("fullScreen",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "fullScreen")
rgb = win32gui.CreateSolidBrush(win32api.RGB(0, 0, 0))
GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND = -10
win32api.SetClassLong(hwndMain, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, rgb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I do.

```
img = np.zeros((900, 1600)) #my aspect ratio is 16x9
cv2.namedWindow("test", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("test", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow("test",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

gives me a fully black screen.  Are you sure you are using the right aspect ratio?

Comment: yes i do, mine is 16x9 as well, it has resolution of (1920x1080)
Which version of opencv do you use? I have opencv2.4.
BTW it happens also if i don't use the full screen mode. I see a white stripe

Comment: I am using opencv 2.4.4  So just to clarify, you have tried manually checking the size and content of your image? or used np.zeros instead of reading in from a file?  I just want to make sure your source of error is not in the creation of your image.  If you run the code posted above you see a strip?  If you change the dimensions given to np.zeros does the size of the strip change?

Comment: yes i have used your code above, with np. zeros.  it looks like there is some problem with cv2.imshow. I have also changed the dimension of that. Tomorrow i will try with another display but i have alreaw tried with 2, maybe something wrong during the installation

Comment: I have copied your code in another computer with different display and still i see this white strip, and if i change the size of the numpy array the size of the strip doesn't change.

Comment: that is really strange.  When you change the size are you changing the aspect ratio as well?

Comment: my resolution is 1280x800 16:10 (i am using another laptop now) so if i write: 'img = np.zeros((800, 1280))' it is supposed to work, does it?

Comment: Also if you have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508010/why-doesnt-opencv-give-this-rectangle-a-colour-using-pythons-cv2?rq=1
You can notice that there is gray strip on top and on the left...