# How do I end a Python Tkinter Image with keyboard input

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

After failing with this topic: [white border while displaying a full image with python and opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948913/white-border-while-displaying-a-full-image-with-python-and-opencv). I have decided to change my method and in order to display a full screen black image i have used PIL and Tkinter libraries.
But i have looked for a way to close my fully black image but i couldn't figure it out.
My solution should looks like the code below, using the keys from openCv.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('background image')
imageFile = "nera.jpg"
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imageFile))
w = image1.width()
h = image1.height()
x = 0
y = 0
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
panel1 = tk.Label(root, image=image1)
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
panel1.image = image1
root.overrideredirect(True)

root.mainloop()

key=cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF
while True:
    if key==ord('d') or key==ord('a')  or key==ord('s') or key==ord('w') or key==27:
        root.destroy()
        print 'ciao
```

How can i close it and do other stuff and then open it again?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems. First of all, you never read a key and the while loop is never reached, because it is *after* `root.mainloop()`.  Second, if the program would enter the loop, it would never leave it because there is no `break`. So to fix your approach, try this instead:

```
# comment out root.mainloop() or just remove the line

while True:
    key=cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF
    if key==ord('d') or key==ord('a')  or key==ord('s') or key==ord('w') or key==27:
        root.destroy()
        print 'ciao'
        break
```

Alternatively, you could just use the tkinter methods to make widgets respond to keypresses, instead of resorting to an ugly openCV hack:

```
root.bind("a", lambda x: root.destroy())
root.bind("d", lambda x: root.destroy())
root.bind("s", lambda x: root.destroy())
root.bind("w", lambda x: root.destroy())
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda x: root.destroy())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method with the openCV hack does not work (i have used that because i am using in my project), without root.mainloop() the black image doesn't appear. But the second it works perfectly!